# После переноса сайта с одного сервера на другой не подгружаются стили

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403

[image: не прогружаются стили в админке]

После переноса сайта с одного ftp на другой, при входе в админку вордпресса не подгружаются стили, в чём может быть ошибка? И как это исправить. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: проверьте пермишены, и наличие отсутствующих файлов на сервере

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562